# Alter translations in jstl fmt without recompile

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, jstl

I'm currently working on an internationalized webapplication in java, using only the standard servlet api (no frameworks). for all static text on the pages like headings, labels etc. I've been using the fmt tag library, backed by properties files in WEB-INF/classes. 
the application is almost done, but the requirement that our client might like to change or update the translations later on, has suddenly been introduced.
Since the properties files are located inside the war, this is not doable without recompiling the app. so, my question is simply: is there any way of updating the properties files inside the war or maybe have the setBundle tag load the files from an external directory. or maybe a third, more clean and correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how the need to change or update a translation could "suddenly" come up--you should always assume that any text in an application might need to be modified, *particularly* translations.

Comment: of course, and it is easily modifiable, provided you have the source code(or unzip/rezip as suggested below, or deploy exploded war). this is also why i hoped there would be a clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in an external folder and add its path to the webapp's runtime classpath. For example, `/var/webapp/conf`. As to adding this path to the webapp's runtime classpath, this depends on the server used. If it's for example Tomcat 6/7, then you need to add it to the `shared.loader` property of `Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties` file.

```
shared.loader = /var/webapp/conf
```

This way it's available in webapp's runtime classpath the usual way and you don't need to repackage the WAR..

Comment: Thanks, this was sort of the kind of solution I was looking for. I'm gonna try it

Comment: Just to follow up. I ended up going with BalusC's solution. Adding the following to jboss-service.xml.
`<classpath codebase="file:///home/peter/properties/" />`
which works for both jboss 4.2 and jboss 6.
so, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

A war is just a zip file. Unzip it, change the properties files, and rezip. No need to recompile anything.

Providing a simple script to do that in a single operation should be easy. You could even use the u (update) option of jar to do it. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html